# In ADCs, what is the number of conversions per sequence?

Tags: microcontroller, analog, adc, microprocessor

I'm dealing with a microcontroller's Analog to Digital Converter (ATD_10B8C) that has a control register who's bit values determine the "number of conversions per sequence". What exactly does this parameter refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an 8 channel ADC (inputs selected by a multiplexer) and you can set the number of channels to be cycled around and ignore the presence of higher number channels if you want. The completion of the conversion of the last channel (as defined by the appropriate register) is the end of the sequence and restarting the sequence will commence at the lowest number channel.